# Change groupType of ActiveDirectory Group

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Does anyone know, how to change the `groupType` attribute of an AD group via C#?

After correctly retrieving the group, I tried the following, but this throws a `DirectoryServicesCOMException`:

```
group.Properties["groupType"].Value = ActiveDs.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_ENUM.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_GLOBAL_GROUP | ActiveDs.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_ENUM.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED;
group.CommitChanges();
```

Do you know a way to change the `groupType` property for an existing group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing which exception you get, I would make the following suggestion:

Ensure that you are attempting a valid conversion
Universal -> Domain Local or Global
Domain Local -> Universal
Global -> Universal

If you can't do it with ADuC, you won't be able to do it in your programm, so double check there.

Comment: You were right. The conversion I tried didn't work. With other conversions the code works. Do you have any idea how to get the group to the desired type? My only idea is to create a new one and copy all the members from the old to the new one. Or do you know a better way?

Comment: If you create a new group, it will have a different SID.  Even if you give it exactly the same name, it won't have permissions where your current group does.